# How to create a date range in the format of YYYY-MM-DD from start to end in Golang?

Tags: go, time

Let's say our inputs are `start_date=2022-01-01` and `end_date=2022-01-05`. How I can get an input like below:

```
2022-01-01
2022-01-02
2022-01-03
2022-01-04
```

I'm able to parse start and end using `time.Parse` and get the days in between using `.Sub` and then iterating over the range and create string dates.
I was wondering if there is any method or better solution for date range creation in `Go`?

Comment: Use a loop, starting from `start`, iterating while date is before `end`, and for incrementing, use `Time.AddDate(0, 0, 1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
const (
    layout = "2006-01-02"
)

func main() {
    startDate, _ := time.Parse(layout, "2022-01-01")
    endDate, _ := time.Parse(layout, "2022-01-05")

    for date := startDate; date.Before(endDate); date = date.AddDate(0, 0, 1) {
        fmt.Println(date.Format(layout))
    }
}
```

This will give you:

```
2022-01-01
2022-01-02
2022-01-03
2022-01-04
```

[**Full example**](https://go.dev/play/p/xl5EYqCd3ZT)

Answer (score 0):

Go doesn’t use yyyy-mm-dd layout to format a time. Instead, you format a special layout parameter

**Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 MST 2006**

the same way as the time or date should be formatted. (This date is easier to remember when written as **01/02 03:04:05PM ‘06 -0700**.)

```
const (
    layoutISO = "2006-01-02"
    layoutUS  = "January 2, 2006"
)
date := "1999-12-31"
t, _ := time.Parse(layoutISO, date)
fmt.Println(t)                  // 1999-12-31 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
fmt.Println(t.Format(layoutUS)) // December 31, 1999
```

The function

- **time.Parse** parses a date string, and
- **Format** formats a time.Time.

They have the following signatures:

```
 func Parse(layout, value string) (Time, error)
  func (t Time) Format(layout string) string
```

you can use this for date range

```
const (
    layoutISO = "2006-01-02"
    layoutUS  = "January 2, 2006"
)

func main() {
    date := "1999-12-31"
    t, _ := time.Parse(layoutISO, date)
    fmt.Println(t)                  // 1999-12-31 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
    fmt.Println(t.Format(layoutUS)) // December 31, 1999
    
    
    startDate, _ := time.Parse(layoutISO, "2022-01-01")
    endDate, _ := time.Parse(layoutISO, "2022-01-05")
    for date := startDate; date.Before(endDate); date = date.AddDate(0, 0, 1) {
        fmt.Println(date.Format(layoutISO))
    }

}
```